# PHP Selectbox automatic

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

Goodmorning,

I have a question I have a selectbox with data from the database I want when u select the number out of the list the next selectbox below it fills data with something else RELATED to the first one that also contains a query from the database.

so basically it is I select Klantvraag numbers in selectbox 1 when U select the box with number 5 the second box select Contract numbers related to that Klantvraag numbers.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reload the page, or use an ajax request, e.g. via jQuery; [ajax jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I have totally no experience with jQuery could u point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think this is what you are looking for.

http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html

BR.